# Using an led tv as a computer monitor

Tags: hdtv

I want my television to power on when i turn on my computer, and then power off when i turn off the computer. I have a 32" insignia led tv and a dell computer.
Is this possible? I dont want to have to turn on the computer, then have to use the remote to turn on the tv. It is currently connected with an hdmi cable.
I'm not sure if there are any settings that can do this, or if i connect it using a different kind of cable. Help!

Comment: First you need to enable _HDMI Control_ on the TV: this may be a general setting, or it may be per port; there may be an additional _Auto On_ setting that you need to set. If you have a BluRay player or set-top box which is set up to turn on the TV when it is powered on, copy its HDMI port settings. On the PC side it's complicated: it may depend on the graphics card, OS and driver and on how your PC is turned off: sleeping may not turn off the TV, but shut down and hibernate probably will. Also, inactivity screen blanking may or may not turn off the TV. You'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

TVs can be controlled over HDMI using [CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC).  This includes powering on and off.

This requires two things - TV that is CEC capable, and a source that can emit CEC signals.  You can check CEC support in your TV, but it is unlikely your Dell machine will be CEC capable.  In this case, there are USB based CEC dongles that can inject CEC commands into the HDMI connection, such as from Pulse Eight.

An alternative would be to get an IR blaster, and connect it to the PC.  When it boots, it could send the "Turn on" signal to the TV.